# Obtaining Iptables info using a script

Tags: ubuntu, script, ipv4

I have an iptables rule and I have to write a script that gets the numbers of packets and bytes target for that rule. I know that that command `iptables -L -v -x` shows that info, but I don't know how to extract it with a script.

It will be just a single rule in forward chain. Can somebody help me with this script? I have to show the answer on the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply redirect the answer in a file, using a command like this:

```
# iptables -L -v -x >> ~/iptable-stats.txt
```

Then, you can extract the right argument easier as it was shown on the prompt.